# How to get rid of Introductory Offer with Free Trial when user already used this offer?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, storekit

I have in-app purchase with productId ‘yearly’. This product contains Introductory offer - Free trial for 7 days. I have function which grabs this product from store. So when I buy this product at the first time I can manage this product and show trial description in UI and when I start billing process I receive trial details in billing dialog - everything is fine.

But if I made refund of this purchase and try to fetch this product again from store. I still receive trial description. But in this time I don’t receive trial price in billing process dialog.

I want to show only actual information about product. If it has 'active' trial offer - good, let's show it. If user somehow used this offer in the past - good too but we shouldn't show trial info in UI. How can I detect when product with introductory offer won’t contain trial price in billing process?

P.S I tested it only in TestFlight. Should I test it after release?